# Never success to plotting graph by python igraph

Tags: python, igraph, cairo

So many times after i type `plot(g, layout=layout)` poping out the error message:

[image]

I installed Cairo and py2cairo successfully as the doc said, but it didn't work.

I'm using mac os 10.8.x and I use ipython to try to plot as the tutorial.

Comment: What does `import cairo` tell you at the Python prompt? Does it work, if not, Cairo is not installed properly or it is installed in a different Python installation than the one used by `ipython`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the python's real path by `which python`

Then, check the `sys.path` of current python.

I found that the brew install cairo is not installed in the python sys.path, so I have to 
add another PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

to my `.bashrc`.